# Are nested dependency injections acceptable practice in golang?

Tags: go, dependency-injection

Are there any problems with nested dependency injection? For example:

```
type ParentService struct{
    db *sql.DB
}

type UsefulChildStruct struct{
    attrA int
    attrB int

    db *sql.Db

}

func NewParent(db *sql.DB) *ParentService{
    return &ParentService{db: db}
}

func (p *ParentService) NewChild() *UsefulChildStruct{
    return &UsefulChildStruct{db: p.db}
}

func (c *UsefulChildStruct) DoSomething(){
    x := c.db.SomeQuery
}

func (c *UsefulChildStruct) DoAnotherThing(){
    x := c.db.SomeQuery
}

func main(){
    db := getDB()
    parent := NewParent(db)
    child := parent.NewChild(parent.db)
}
```

The rationale is so all data types created by ParentService would be able to use the dependency too.

Comment: No real issues except complexity.  But you're not doing dependency injection here.  You're depending directly on the structs, which depends directly on the SQL DB struct types.  Dependency injection in Go is usually managed using _interfaces_ to reference dependency types, which then allows you to mock or wrap those types seamlessly without the package _using_ those dependencies needing to know that they've been mocked or wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in doing that.But you haven't created any value except complexity!

Another issue is you limited yourself,  if you want to use differnet db for UsefulChildStruct later, you have to change your code. This is a violation of open for extension close for modification principle

Comment: @meowmeow Was this helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should do something like this but i'm not sure about syntax.

```
package main

type Storage interface {
    Get() (*Items, err)
}

type Items struct {
    foo string
}


// Postgres database
type postgres struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func newPostgres(db *sql.DB) *postgres {
    return &postgres{db}
}

func (p *postgres) Get() (*items, error){
    // query something here
    return nil, nil
}



// Mongo database
type mongodb struct {
    mongo *session // i'am not sure about this 
}

func newMongo (session) *mongdb {
    return &mongdb{mongo: session}
}

func (m *mongdob) Get() (*items, error) {
    // query something here
    return nil, nil
}


// mock database
type mockDB struct {}

func newMock () mockDB {
    return mockDB{}
}

func (m mockDB) Get() (*items, error) {
    // query something here
    return nil, nil
}



type ParentService struct{
    db Storage
}

func NewParent(db Storage) *ParentService{
    return &ParentService{db: db}
}

func (p *ParentService) doSomething() {
    items, err := p.db.Get()
    // do something with items
}



func main(){
    db := connectPostgres()
    pStorage := newPostgres(db)
    parent := NewParent(pStorage)

    sess := connectMongo()
    mStorage := newMongo(sess)
    parent := NewParent(mStorage)

    mockStorage := mockDB()
    parent := NewParent(mockStorage)
}
```